# USB 3.0 Network Adapter - Chipset ax88179

Tags: release-loki, usb, ethernet, dell

All, I have a **Dell XPS 13 series 9350**, with elementary OS Loki.

I have purchased a USB-C 3.0 Multi-Function Adapter, 3 USB ports and an Ethernet 10/100/1000 with the ax88179 chipset.  The USB ports are working but the Ethernet port is not.  When I plug the device in I get a window that says ***"disconnected Ethernet network"*** ... when I go to Network Settings ***"Wired Network"*** does not exist.

### LSUSB Output:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

I do not see any Ethernet device (though from my research the ax88179 is part of the 4.4.0 kernal)

Any advice on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

All ... so I ran a

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then

```
$ sudo reboot
```

All is right in the world !!!!